# Android Custom Calendar View

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have implemented 7 days of week calendar view for android. But I want to implement 5 day of week custom calendar view for android. So how can i hide Saturday and Sunday. Can you please give me some demo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't break at 5 and go further at 8.